ERROR 404 AL INTENTAR ACCEDER A UNA RUTA EN SPRING BOOT
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación CRUD utilizando Spring Boot con Thymeleaf y el sistema de gestión H2. Inicialmente, la aplicación funcionaba correctamente y podía acceder a las rutas específicas sin problemas. Sin embargo, al agregar la funcionalidad para cargar imágenes y guardarlas en la base de datos, me encuentro con un problema.
Después de agregar este nuevo campo de imagen, cuando intento recargar mi aplicación, en la consola de la aplicación Spring Boot todo parece estar bien, pero en la web me muestra un error 404. El mensaje de error específico es el siguiente:
    Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jun 11 13:10:01 CST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

Aquí está mi controlador:
 package com.example.application.controller;

import com.example.application.domain.User;
import com.example.application.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.application.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class HomeControllers {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    private static final String appName = "ThymeleafTour"; 
    
    @GetMapping("/Thymeleaf")
    public String home(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Guest") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("title", appName);
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String users(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("usuarios", userRepository.findAll());
        return "users";
    }

    @GetMapping("/agregar")
    public String addUserForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("usuario", new User());
        return "agregar";
    }

    @PostMapping("/agregar")
    public String addUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("usuario") User usuario, @RequestParam("imagen") MultipartFile imagen, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
        // Método addUser aquí
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/eliminar")
    public String eliminarUsuario(@RequestParam("nombre") String nombre, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        // Método eliminarUsuario aquí
    }

    @GetMapping("/editar")
    public String editar(@RequestParam("nombre") String nombre, Model model) {
        // Método editar aquí
    }

    @PostMapping("/actualizar")
    public String actualizar(@Valid @ModelAttribute("usuario") User usuario, @RequestParam("imagen") MultipartFile imagen, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model) {
        // Método actualizar aquí
    }
}

Y aquí está el HTML para la página a la que estoy intentando acceder:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Lista de Usuarios</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-content">
        <h1>Lista de Usuarios</h1>

        <div th:if="${successMessage}" class="success-message">
            <p th:text="${successMessage}"></p>
        </div>

        <div th:if="${errorMessage}" class="error-message">
            <p th:text="${errorMessage}"></p>
        </div>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Edad</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="usuario : ${usuarios}">
                    <td th:text="${usuario.nombre}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${usuario.edad}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${usuario.correo}"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a th:href="@{/downloadFile/{id}(id=${usuario.id})}" target="_blank">Descargar Imagen</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a th:href="@{/editar(id=${usuario.id})}">Editar</a>
                        <form th:action="@{/eliminar}" method="post" style="display:inline;">
                            <input type="hidden" th:value="${usuario.id}" name="id">
                            <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <a href="/agregar">Agregar Nuevo Usuario</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

La ruta a la que estoy intentando acceder es
localhost:8080/users

He revisado la configuración del controlador, reiniciado la aplicación y verificado las dependencias de Thymeleaf y Spring MVC en mi archivo pom.xml. Sin embargo, el problema persiste.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme a identificar qué podría estar causando este error 404 y cómo solucionarlo? ¡Cualquier sugerencia o ayuda sería muy apreciada!

Si hace falta alguna otra parte del código que deseen conocer con gusto lo proporciono
